# program other than apache listen on 3000 for https (ProxyPassReverse)

Tags: node.js, apache, tcpdump, fastify

I am trying to get fastify listen on port 3000 for https requests . Fastify is listening on port 3000 , but when I am trying to send a curl command `curl -k https://example.com:3000/ -v` , I am getting this

```
 Trying 35.245.34.146...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (35.245.34.146) port 3000 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

I setup tcpdump to capture traffic on port 3000 and here is what I got

```
14:11:23.046591 IP 100.8.170.2.52475 > 10.150.0.2.3000: tcp 0
        0x0000:  4500 0040 0000 4000 3a06 2816 6408 aa02  E..@..@.:.(.d...
        0x0010:  0a96 0002 ccfb 0bb8 2524 14bd 0000 0000  ........%$......
        0x0020:  b002 ffff 6070 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0306  ....`p..........
        0x0030:  0101 080a 4ad5 607f 0000 0000 0402 0000  ....J.`.........
14:11:23.046638 IP 10.150.0.2.3000 > 100.8.170.2.52475: tcp 0
        0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 221a 0a96 0002  E..<..@.@.".....
        0x0010:  6408 aa02 0bb8 ccfb 2b60 9883 2524 14be  d.......+`..%$..
        0x0020:  a012 fd00 18d1 0000 0204 058c 0402 080a  ................
        0x0030:  9e6d c7ce 4ad5 607f 0103 0307            .m..J.`.....
14:11:23.066491 IP 100.8.170.2.52475 > 10.150.0.2.3000: tcp 0
        0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 3a06 2822 6408 aa02  E..4..@.:.("d...
        0x0010:  0a96 0002 ccfb 0bb8 2524 14be 2b60 9884  ........%$..+`..
        0x0020:  8010 0814 6de8 0000 0101 080a 4ad5 6092  ....m.......J.`.
        0x0030:  9e6d c7ce                                .m..
14:11:23.086786 IP 100.8.170.2.52475 > 10.150.0.2.3000: tcp 235
        0x0000:  4500 011f 0000 4000 3a06 2737 6408 aa02  E.....@.:.'7d...
        0x0010:  0a96 0002 ccfb 0bb8 2524 14be 2b60 9884  ........%$..+`..
        0x0020:  8018 0814 432f 0000 0101 080a 4ad5 60a7  ....C/......J.`.
        0x0030:  9e6d c7ce 1603 0100 e601 0000 e203 03da  .m..............
        0x0040:  6cf3 41d6 0aba 42c3 5e03 d368 bb85 d01c  l.A...B.^..h....
        0x0050:  576a 3ce9 e7b8 208f 49d6 0c28 094d 5000  Wj<.....I..(.MP.
        0x0060:  005c c030 c02c c028 c024 c014 c00a 009f  .\.0.,.(.$......
        0x0070:  006b 0039 cca9 cca8 ccaa ff85 00c4 0088  .k.9............
        0x0080:  0081 009d 003d 0035 00c0 0084 c02f c02b  .....=.5...../.+
        0x0090:  c027 c023 c013 c009 009e 0067 0033 00be  .'.#.......g.3..
        0x00a0:  0045 009c 003c 002f 00ba 0041 c011 c007  .E...<./...A....
        0x00b0:  0005 0004 c012 c008 0016 000a 00ff 0100  ................
        0x00c0:  005d 0000 0015 0013 0000 1075 7064 6174  .].......example
        0x00d0:  6573 6469 6172 792e 636f 6d00 0b00 0201         .com.....
        0x00e0:  0000 0a00 0800 0600 1d00 1700 1800 0d00  ................
        0x00f0:  1c00 1a06 0106 03ef ef05 0105 0304 0104  ................
        0x0100:  03ee eeed ed03 0103 0302 0102 0300 1000  ................
        0x0110:  0e00 0c02 6832 0868 7474 702f 312e 31    ....h2.http/1.1
14:11:23.086829 IP 10.150.0.2.3000 > 100.8.170.2.52475: tcp 0
        0x0000:  4500 0034 6647 4000 4006 bbda 0a96 0002  E..4fG@.@.......
        0x0010:  6408 aa02 0bb8 ccfb 2b60 9884 2524 15a9  d.......+`..%$..
        0x0020:  8010 01f9 18c9 0000 0101 080a 9e6d c7f7  .............m..
        0x0030:  4ad5 60a7                                J.`.
```

fastify setup

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const fastify = require('fastify')(
      { logger: true},

     { 
      http2: true,
      https: {
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'../../etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem')),
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'../../etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem')),
      secureProtocol: 'TLSv1.2'
    
              }
     }
);
```

http works fine `curl -k http://example.com:3000/ -v`  and i get response back

I have also tried making this change in  `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf` in `

```
<VirtualHost *:443 *:3000>
```

but I get same result `CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number` in curl command

can someone please help to see  how can I get response back for https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented [`ProxyPassReverse`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) from Apache to achieve fastify sending requests over https using the same apache tunnel that is already opened (port 443) instead of opening a different port

Include this in your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf` file on apache2

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /path http://127.0.0.1:3000/path1
ProxyPassReverse /path http://127.0.0.1:3000/path1
```

where `/path` is path from incoming request from client (browser) and `/path1` is the path that will be located on Fastify server

On fastify side , your server.js will look like thuis in its very basic form

```
fastify.register(httpProxy, {
    upstream: 'https://upstream.com',
    prefix: '/path1',
     
    });
```

make sure fastify listens on 3000, no need to get fastify listen on https in this setup

Finally ,an example ,  the request from client will look like this.

`https://yourdomain.com/path/svc/search` and in this setup it will be proxied to `https://upstream.com/svc/search`